# Eclipse: Edit code parser

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, sdcc

I am using a plugin for Eclipse (The Eclipse plugin of [SDCC](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/index.php#Download)).

This works fine (so far) but the problem is the inline assembly..

[image]

it is pretty annoying that the parser marks this code as syntax error
and furthermore that it marks symbols which are defined in a header file.

Therefore I want to extend the plugin a little bit such that the parser(s)
ignore the inline assembly part since the SDCC compiler will complain about it
anyway if it finds an error.

I've seen that there is an error parse since CDT 7.0 but I am not sure if this is 
the right place to look at.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place mouse pointer over highlighted code, then press F2 to have focus in popup suggestion window. At left corner of this window exists icon, click on such icon opens problematic item.
By setting/removing checkbox 'Text As', editor with highlighted code will be change view as well.
Usually they are all accessible through Window->Preferences->General->Editors->-Text Editors-> Annotations.
I used it on kepler CDT.

Comment: Well, I have no idea why this works. Everything between `__asm` and `__endasm;` now does not get marked. Everything not in between does. No clue why but thanks!